# Problems resampling Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

just starting out using Pandas and am having trouble resampling a DataFrame.  I read the data from EXCEL and print the first 10 lines so

`print df[:5]`

gives this

```
                 Date           pnew
0 2009-12-23 16:41:00       4.242328
1 2009-12-24 16:41:00       4.248494
2 2009-12-25 16:41:00       4.257310
3 2009-12-26 16:41:00       4.262042
4 2009-12-27 16:41:00       4.264798
```

which is identical to the data in the XL file.  However, there are missing days in the later data so I want to fill them with NaN's.  My code looks like this

```
    dg = df.asfreq('D')
    print(dg)
```

but now I get this:

```
           Date           pnew
1970-01-01  NaT            NaN
```

Not really what I was expecting ... I think the answer is trivial (if you know it ...) but I'm flummoxed.  All suggestions welcome - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`asfreq` only works when your date column is the index:

```
s="""Date,pnew
2009-12-23 16:41:00,4.242328
2009-12-24 16:41:00,4.248494
2009-12-25 16:41:00,4.257310
2009-12-27 16:41:00,4.264798"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s))
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df.set_index('Date').asfreq('D')

                         pnew
Date                         
2009-12-23 16:41:00  4.242328
2009-12-24 16:41:00  4.248494
2009-12-25 16:41:00  4.257310
2009-12-26 16:41:00       NaN
2009-12-27 16:41:00  4.264798
```

Comment: Thanks Yo_Chris, I assumed it was implicit that the time index was in the first field, but that helped.  Have need to sort out the next issue